# Thinkfan does not start automatically

Tags: lubuntu, fan

I have spent several hours trying to get `thinkfan` to work on my Lenovo T420/Lubuntu 16.04.

The problem that I currently have is that it does not automatically start with booting.

Furthermore, the program cannot be started with

```
sudo systemctl enable thinkfan
```

or

```
sudo systemctl enable thinkfan.service
```

Both those commands yield the following output:

```
[sudo] password for martin: 
Synchronizing state of thinkfan.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable thinkfan
```

… but the fan is still running on "auto" mode

```
martin@heat-200-lu:~$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
status:     enabled
speed:      3987
level:      auto
commands:   level <level> (<level> is 0-7, auto, disengaged, full-speed)
commands:   enable, disable
commands:   watchdog <timeout> (<timeout> is 0 (off), 1-120 (seconds))
```

… and runs at 4000 rpm although the temperature is fairly low:

```
martin@heat-200-lu:~$ cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input
52000
```

I *can* start thinkfan using

```
martin@heat-200-lu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/thinkfan start
[ ok ] Starting thinkfan (via systemctl): thinkfan.service.
```

… but, as I said, I can't get it to start automatically.

Here are some config files:

```
martin@heat-200-lu:~$ cat /etc/default/thinkfan 
# Should thinkfan be started automatically on boot?
# Only say "yes" when you know what you are doing, have configured
# thinkfan correctly for *YOUR* machine and loaded thinkpad_acpi
# with fan_control=1 (if you have a ThinkPad).
START=yes

# Additional startup parameters
DAEMON_ARGS="-q"


martin@heat-200-lu:~$ cat /etc/thinkfan.conf 
######################################################################
# thinkfan 0.7 example config file
# ================================
#
# ATTENTION: There is only very basic sanity checking on the configuration.
# That means you can set your temperature limits as insane as you like. You
# can do anything stupid, e.g. turn off your fan when your CPU reaches 70°C.
#
# That's why this program is called THINKfan: You gotta think for yourself.
#
######################################################################
#
# IBM/Lenovo Thinkpads (thinkpad_acpi, /proc/acpi/ibm)
# ====================================================
#
# IMPORTANT:
#
# To keep your HD from overheating, you have to specify a correction value for
# the sensor that has the HD's temperature. You need to do this because
# thinkfan uses only the highest temperature it can find in the system, and
# that'll most likely never be your HD, as most HDs are already out of spec
# when they reach 55 °C.
# Correction values are applied from left to right in the same order as the
# temperatures are read from the file.
#
# For example:
# tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 0, 10)
# will add a fixed value of 10 °C the 3rd value read from that file. Check out
# http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Thermal_Sensors to find out how much you may
# want to add to certain temperatures.

#  Syntax:
#  (LEVEL, LOW, HIGH)
#  LEVEL is the fan level to use (0-7 with thinkpad_acpi)
#  LOW is the temperature at which to step down to the previous level
#  HIGH is the temperature at which to step up to the next level
#  All numbers are integers.
#

# I use this on my T61p:
#tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
#tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)

sensor /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp3_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input
sensor /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp2_input

(0, 0,  55)
(1, 48, 60)
(2, 55, 66)
(3, 62, 73)
(4, 66, 79)
(5, 72, 81)
(7, 75, 32767)


martin@heat-200-lu:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf 
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

I welcome any suggestions regarding what might go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed): Put the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf`:

```
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

Then reboot. Then you should be able to `echo level disengaged > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`